# Using alias in cygwin doesn't recognize?

Tags: google-chrome, cygwin, alias, bash

I have the following alias:

```
alias gmail='https://gmail.com'
```

And, I try to execute it as follows in Cygwin:

```
cygstart chrome  gmail
```

But, it treat "gmail" literally as the web address "gmail"  and not the alias `https://gmail.com`

Question:  Why is it not  using the alias?

Comment: zsh has "global aliases" that can do this, but not bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell aliases only apply to the first word in a command. They can not be used to replace strings in the middle of commands.

Consider using a variable instead:

```
gmail='https://gmail.com'
cygstart chrome "$gmail"
```

Comment: Certainly, if `cygstart` is the only command you want to use the url with.

Comment: as @thatotherguy pointed out, the problem is that I want to be able to launch with other programs.